# "Style 'Currency' not found" When trying to format a column from a file created with phpexcel / yii / eexcelview

Tags: phpexcel, yii-extensions

I am using PHPExcel 1.7.9 - (https:// phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/107442) to create an excel file with no issues.  However when I want to format a column in excel, I highlight it and click the "$" icon in the toolbar and the error: "Style 'Currency' not found" pops up. Same happens for "%" and "," , however if I take the long way "right click" -> Format Cell -> select style, it works fine.

I found these articles about the issue, but I don't know how to solve:
[1] http://www.office-archive.com/4-excel/10a63209c2ca163d.htm 
[2] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.worksheet.functions/5PvrI8yCm60

I am using Yii to generate the xls with the "eexcelview" extension

Here is my code to generate the file:

```
    $this->widget('EExcelView', array(
        'title'=>'Title',
        'filename'=> 'Transaction-export-'.date('Y-m-d'),
        'exportButtons' => array('Excel5','CSV'),
        'id'=>'gateway-transaction-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$provider,
        'template'=>"{summary}\n{pager}{exportbuttons}\n\n{items}\n{exportbuttons}\n{pager}",
        'columns'=>array(
                        ...
```

Comment: So is your problem with MS Excel? I don't have a "$" icon in the toolbar in any of my versions of MS Excel

Comment: Yes problem with excel.  see this image for the toolbar:  https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT1bpzfGD_ttMLkSbBv_Y-9lH-RreHsAUR61nCVfmvauewN9xEs

Comment: sample xls file can be downloaded here:  https://www.codeplex.com/Download/AttachmentDownload.ashx?ProjectName=phpexcel&WorkItemId=10749&FileAttachmentId=7105